# i am reading a csv file but it would stop reading the file after a certain number of times

Tags: java

```
 public void processText(String filename){
        int count=0;

        String[] r = new String[178806];
        String line = "";
        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))){
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            r = line.split(",");
            DNode wordObj = new DNode(r[0].toUpperCase(),r[1],r[2],r[3]);
            System.out.println(wordObj);
            count++;
            System.out.println(count);
        }

        }catch(Exception tom){
            System.out.println(tom);
        }
    }
```

it would stop after reading only 2261 lines and stop is there a reason?

i keep getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3

i checked the file if there was something wrong with it but there was nothing wrong

Comment: `r = line.split(",");` looks like this is reading a line that's not structured the way you expect it to be, that is a line with less than 4 fields.

Comment: Also, this `String[] r = new String[178806];` is useless. You're assigning a new value to `r` at each iteration, no need to have it there. Just do `String[] r = line.split(",");` inside the loop.

Comment: You could check the line before creating the `DNode` object and skip the line

Comment: but all the lines have something in them I checked it

Comment: @AbdullahShaibah "something" is not sufficient, it has to be in the form `w.x,y,z`, that is at least four strings separated by commas.

Comment: i think so because i have some strings like this: B2.2.1.2.1.1_Mental or Behavioral Dysfunction

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean with your last comment. You mean there are lines like that, with no commas, so that's the answer to your question?

Comment: can you put DNode declaration ?

Comment: Use your debugger, put a trigger on exception, check the value of the line variable when the debugger pause execution. Or if you prefer the poor man's solution, add a test on `r`'s lenght before the `new DNode` and `System.out.println(line)` when it's lower than 4

Comment: i am not sure what you mean but i think this is what you want                        public DNode(String N, String D,String P,String C)

Comment: Before using line.split(",") just print it to check if the data is correct. ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException means something wrong with the data.

Comment: Aaron i checked the sout(line) and i got this:  pentaerythritol ethoxylate (3/4 EO/OH),crystallisation adjutant,<No Term>,      .  The <No Term> part is not in the file and there is text where it stopped

Comment: I'd check the line in the original file more closely, maybe using an hex editor to check for 1) control characters and 2) encoding.

Comment: Can you please copy/paste that line from the file, as is, inside your question?

Comment: pentaerythritol ethoxylate (3/4 EO/OH),crystallisation adjutant,Disseminated Intravascular Coagulation,B2.2.1.2.1.2_Neoplastic Process           this is what should be found when it reads the file but this is what i get : pentaerythritol ethoxylate (3/4 EO/OH),crystallisation adjutant,<No Term>,

Comment: set the file encoding to UTF-8

Comment: the file encoding is UTF-8